# adding gaps in Semantic UI column

Tags: css, html, layout, semantic-ui

i looked for css grid layouts to learn Semantic UI grid system ([typically here](https://www.quackit.com/html/templates/css_grid_templates.cfm)), i tried to make margin using the "column" class but it messes the hole grid.
i just want small gaps like 2px in the grid. this is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ussama/xpvt214o/918311/)
i checked the documentation there is no mention to gaps.
thanks

```
<div class="ui equal width stackable divided  grid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="red column">
            <header></header>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="three column row">
        <div class="three wide blue column">
            <nav></nav>
        </div>
        <div class=" column">
            <div class="ui  grid">
                   <div class=" column row">
                        <div class="thirteen wide yellow column">
                            <article></article>
                        </div>
                    <div class="three wide pink column"></div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="teal column">
                       <footer></footer>
                        </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try the `padded` class to the grid?

Comment: @ManojKumar i did try all the options in the documentation :/ could not make difference